# How to pass the path parameter to the Pydantic model?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Is there some way to do the following?

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Item(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/items/{item_id}")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item
```

I want to have the `item_id` path parameter value inside the `Item` model.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Pydantic in FastAPI is used to define data model. You can do as follows:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Item(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str] = None
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/items/{item_id}")
async def create_item(item_id, item: Item):
    item.id = item_id
    return item
```

Please, note that `id` is declared as optional to avoid validation problems with body parameters in the request. Indeed, you are not going to pass the `id` in the body but in the path.

If necessary, you can also decouple the request- from the response-model (see [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#add-an-output-model)). It depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant, or how safe this solution is, but you can do:

```py
@app.post("/items/{item.id}")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nicer way to do this using FastAPI [`Depends`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/).

First forget making it optional, we don't have to do that song and dance with this method.

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None


app = FastAPI()
```

Then we're going to create a `Depends` (which is really just a function) that will allow us to construct the object using all parts of the request.

```
def make_item(req: Request):
  path_params = req.path_params
  body_obj = req.json()
  return Item.model_validate(path_params | body_obj)
```

Here we just took the path params and merged them with the body to construct the final model. Don't worry about it not being super general right now we're going to fix that. But here's how it looks on your method.

```
@app.post("/items/{id}")
async def create_item(item: Item = Depends(make_item)):
    return item
```

It would be really annoying to have to make one of these helper methods for each class so let's make a factory.

```
def make_model(model_type):
  def _make_model(req: Request):
    path_params = req.path_params
    body_obj = req.json()
    return model_type.model_validate(path_params | body_obj)
  return _make_model
```

So here's how that would look on your method.

```
@app.post("/items/{id}")
async def create_item(item: Item = Depends(make_model(Item))):
    return item
```

If that's fine with you then we can stop here but we can make it less verbose with some application of `typing`.

```
T = TypeVar("T")

def make_model(model_type: Type[T]) -> T:
  def _make_model(req: Request):
    path_params = req.path_params
    body_obj = req.json()
    return model_type.model_validate(path_params | body_obj)
  return Depends(_make_model)
```

Here we moved the `Depends` into the make_model function and we fibbed a little bit on the typing so that it will type correctly once FastAPI is done with it.

```
@app.post("/items/{id}")
async def create_item(item=make_model(Item)):
    return item
```

It might not look it from the type signature but `reveal_type` and your editor's autocomplete now know that `item` is of type `Item` without you having to repeat yourself if you don't want to. It's a little bit magic but FastAPI is a lot of magic so I wouldn't feel too bad about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace your `id: str` with `id: Optional [str] = None`
2. Replace your c`reate_item (item: Item)` with `create_item (item_id, item: Item):`
3. Add `item.id = item_id` under your `async`. Obviously then you leave the ruo return item